# Detect mouse clicks on circles on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, click, mouseevent

I'm new to canvas and I'm trying to listen to mouse clicks on the circles that I previously drew on canvas. I'm trying to change the colour of the circles (maybe to green) when I click on them.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


var radius = 15;
for (var i = 0; i < 600; i += 100) {
  var x = 100 + i;
  var y = 100;
  draw_circle(i, x, y, radius);
}

function draw_circle(ID, x, y, radius) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SVG, it would be easy - a circle is an element, and can have a click handler, and has `fill` that you can manipulate to change colour.

With Canvas, you need to:

- save the data for each circle you draw (center and radius)
- capture click on canvas as `cx, cy`
- check every circle data `x, y, r` you have, see whether `dx * dx + dy * dy < r * r`, where `dx = cx - x`, `dy = cy - y`. Circles that satisfy this equation were clicked
- repaint the circle

Answer (score 4):

Just add the arc path again and use `isPointInPath()` with the mouse position. Only one arc can be tested at once, but it's fast to clear and add new paths. Do this in a loop.

## Example

```js
var c = document.querySelector("canvas"), ctx = c.getContext("2d");

getArc(50, 50, 40);
ctx.fill();

c.onclick = function(e) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),   // get abs. position of canvas
      x = e.clientX - rect.left,             // adjust mouse-position
      y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  
  getArc(50, 50, 40);                        // get path wo/ filling/stroking it
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(x, y)) alert("Clicked");
};

function getArc(x, y, r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The other approach is to use math and trigonometry:

```
// at this point we have the mouse position, so:
var dx = x - arcX,
    dy = y - arcY,
    dist = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy));

if (dist <= radius) { ...clicked... };
```

Tip: you can skip squaring the dist by using r<sup>2</sup> instead.

Answer (score -1):

With Canvas, you can use function addEventListener. There are quite a few mouse events you can detect: mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseout and mouseover.
Here is a example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
      <style>
            html,
            body {
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 100%;
                 margin: 0px;
            }
      </style>
      <script>
            function initialize() {
                 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                 canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
            }
            function doMouseDown() {
                 canvas_X = event.pageX;
                 canvas_Y = event.pageY;
                 alert("X = " + canvas_X + "Y = " + canvas_Y);
            }
      </script>
</head>
<body>
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```